# Firefox WebExtension options page - How to save/restore preferences from storage.local?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'll start my saying I'm a JavaScript newbie (I'm more of a Bash guy)...

I'm trying to create a Firefox WebExtension to disable the Ctrl+Q shortcut and play a sound when Ctrl+Q is pressed. I'd also like to have a user choose from a small list of sounds in an options menu. So far, *all of that is working*.

The only snag I'm hitting is when the user changes a sound and clicks "Save", the new sound isn't played on Ctrl+Q until the extension is reloaded.

Doing some Googling, I think the problem is related to the fact that [storage API is asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage). From what I can gather, I need to use a callback to get the sound option after it is set. Is that not what I'm doing below? The option is set in options.js and then background.js plays the sound.

I'd appreciate any help.

**options.js**

```
// Saves options to browser.storage
function save_options() {
  browser.storage.local.set({
    favoriteSound: document.getElementById('CtrlQSound').value,
    }, function() {
      // Update status to let user know options were saved.
      var status = document.getElementById('status');
      status.textContent = 'Options saved.';
      setTimeout(function() {
        status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);
  });
};

// Restores select box state using the preferences stored in browser.storage
function restore_options() {
  // Use default value sound = 'Sound0'
  browser.storage.local.get({
    favoriteSound: 'Sound0',
  }, function(items) {
    document.getElementById('CtrlQSound').value = items.favoriteSound;
  });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', save_options);
```

**background.js**

```
browser.storage.local.get("favoriteSound", function(result) {
  browser.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(SoundToggle) {
    if (result.favoriteSound == "Sound0"){
      new Audio("Sound0.ogg").play();
    }
    else if (result.favoriteSound == "Sound1"){
      new Audio("Sound1.ogg").play();
    }
    else if (result.favoriteSound == "Sound2"){
      new Audio("Sound2.ogg").play();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You are using the `browser.*` namespace, which expects to return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) for asynchronous functions, not use callbacks. If you want to use callbacks, you need to use the `chrome.*` namespace. So, basically change all of your API calls from `browser.storage.local.set()` to `chrome.storage.local.set()`. Doing so will, generally, result in your extension being functional on both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox uses Promise objects, not callbacks. On a Promise, you can call "then" with a success and failure handler. Like this:

```
browser.storage.local.set({
    favoriteSound: document.getElementById('CtrlQSound').value
}).then(onSuccess, onError);

function onSuccess() {
    // Saving into storage.local succeeded

    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Options saved.';
    setTimeout(function() {
        status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);

function onError() {
    // Saving into storage local failed.
    // You might want to use a notification to display this error / warning to the user.
});
```

If you're developing for Chrome, you have to use callbacks. Or you could use "chrome." instead of "browser." if you want to use callbacks instead of Promises.